# How to toggle show/hide for div in react

Tags: javascript, jquery, reactjs

Currently building a web-app in Reactjs.

I have the following component in Render() :

```
                <div className="doc-preview">
                    <a href="javascript:void(0)" id="" data-title={article.title}
                       className="dl-docpreview-icon inline-block" data-toggle="modal" data-target={"#"+article.title} >
                        <i className="pe-7s-search"></i>
                    </a>
                    <iframe ref={article.title} id={article.title} className={'doc-preview-block hidden '+ article.title} src={article.uri} width='400' height='300' onClick={self.togglePreview(article.title)} allowfullscreen webkitallowfullscreen></iframe>
                </div>
```

I want to implement the togglePreview action so that on each click the iframe is shown or hidden for a specific element. How can I do so ? I tried using the React.findDOMNode(this.refs[article.title]) but received the following warning :

```
Warning: Article is accessing getDOMNode or findDOMNode inside its render(). render() should be a pure function of props and state. It should never access something that requires stale data from the previous render, such as refs. Move this logic to componentDidMount and componentDidUpdate instead.
```

How can I proceed to implement such a logic ?

Comment: you seem to be using `React.findDOMNode(...)` inside the `render` function. as the _warning_ suggests, you have to move that to a `componentDidMount` method and change `state` there. And based on that `state`, show or hide the `iframe` element.

Comment: @TahirAhmed   here's my function

`togglePreview(title) {
        React.findDOMNode(this.refs[title]).classList.remove("hidden");
    },`

how can I put that inside the componentDidMount method ?

Comment: I see. store a reference in `componentDidMount` for `React.findDOMNode(...)` e.g. `componentDidMount() { this.iFrame = React.findDOMNode(this.refs[title]); }` and then in your `togglePreview` function, you could: `this.iFrame.classList.remove('hidden');`. Try that.

Answer (score 0):

It is complaining because `self.togglePreview(article.title)` is being executed within the render function. Did you intend to use `.bind` to curry `article.title` to the callback? As in this:

```
onClick={self.togglePreview.bind(article.title)}
```

Answer (score 0):

I could be wrong but I think you need to listen to the `onClick` event separately, perform logic in there and set a `state` inside it for the visibility of your `iframe` object. And then use that `state` to show or hide that `iframe`.

Something like this (in ES6 syntax):

```
...
constructor {
  this.state.isIFrameDisplayed = false;
  this.articles = [{ title: ..., uri: ... }, { title: ..., uri: ... }];
  this.state.currentArticleTitle = '';
  this.state.isIFrameDisplayed = false;
}
componentDidMount() {
  this.setState({
    currentArticleTitle: this.articles[0].title,
    isIFrameDisplayed: true
  });
}
onClickIFrame() {
  if (this.state.currentArticleTitle === this.state.articles[0].title) {
    this.setState({ isIFrameDisplayed: false });
  } else {
    this.setState({ isIFrameDisplayed: true });
  }
}
render() {
  var iFrame = this.state.isIFrameDisplayed ? <iframe ref={article.title} id={article.title} className={'doc-preview-block hidden '+ article.title} src={article.uri} width='400' height='300' onClick={this.onClickIFrame} allowfullscreen webkitallowfullscreen></iframe> : '';
  return (
    ...
    {iFrame}
    ...
  );
}
...
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

This is the simple way.

```
                    render: function() {
                        var showIframe = conditionShow == true ? {} : {display: 'none'};
                        return (
                                <div className="doc-preview">
                                        <a href="javascript:void(0)" id="" data-title={article.title}
                                             className="dl-docpreview-icon inline-block" data-toggle="modal" data-target={"#"+article.title} >
                                                <i className="pe-7s-search"></i>
                                        </a>
                                        <div style={showIframe}>
                                            <iframe ref={article.title} id={article.title} className={'doc-preview-block hidden '+ article.title} src={article.uri} width='400' height='300' onClick={self.togglePreview(article.title)} allowfullscreen webkitallowfullscreen></iframe>
                                        </div>
                                </div>
                                )
                            }
```

Be aware that the iframe will render regardless of whether it shows or not. If that is to much of a performance hit you would use the following.

```
                    render: function() {
                        var hideIframe = conditionShow == true ? false : true;
                        return (
                                <div className="doc-preview">
                                        <a href="javascript:void(0)" id="" data-title={article.title}
                                             className="dl-docpreview-icon inline-block" data-toggle="modal" data-target={"#"+article.title} >
                                                <i className="pe-7s-search"></i>
                                        </a>
                                        <IframeComponent hide={hideIframe} />
                                </div>
                                )
                            }
```

IframeComponent

```
                    render: function() {
                        if (this.props.hide) return null;
                        return (
                                <iframe ref={article.title} id={article.title} className={'doc-preview-block hidden '+ article.title} src={article.uri} width='400' height='300' onClick={self.togglePreview(article.title)} allowfullscreen webkitallowfullscreen></iframe>
                                )
                            }
```